# GridView RowCommand event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that looks something like this:

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="GridView1"
    AllowPaging="true"
    OnRowCommand="RowCommand"
    OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging"
    Runat="server">
    <Columns>
        ...
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" ButtonType="Button" CommandName="ItemExport" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("EXPORT") %>'
                    Text="Export" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        ...
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Here is `RowCommand`:

```
protected void RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "ItemExport")
    {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Clicking the button is not firing the `RowCommand` event at all. However, `RowCommand` fires when I click a page index in the GridView's pager.

Comment: When are you binding your grid to the DataSource, only `if(!Postback)`?!

Comment: Yep, the problem was the binding was not wrapped in a `if(!isPostBack)` statement.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You must **not** bind your grid on postbacks in Page_Load, only when something changed that causes the Grid to reload data(f.e. Sorting,Paging) and only in the appropriate event-handlers.

Another possible reason: Have you disabled ViewState somewhere?

Comment: Can't believe this haunted me for hours...just sitting here staring blankly into some none functioning ASP.NET code...all because I had set EnableViewState="false"  :@

Comment: When I bind GridView in if(!IsPostBack), pager does not work :(

Comment: @MazdakShojaie You have to add an event handler for the GridView.PageIndexChanged event, and rebind in that handler. Check out this MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: For me it was the "EnableViewState" set to TRUE on the grdiview.  Set that to FALSE & it started working.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Use `CausesValidation="false"` in button tag. It can solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I just had a colleague who encountered the same problem; his was caused by the `onrowcommand=` attribute not being set in the `asp:GridView` element. This should be set to the name of the handler which will be handling the event.

... just in case someone has the same issue!

Answer (score 3):

Put the `grid.Databind()` inside `if (!IsPostBack)`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        grid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your code is like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGrid(dgv);
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

    }
}
```

Put `BindGrid()` inside the `!isPostBack` block

Answer (score 2):

Tried the above answers and still could not get a post back. Ended up being a **Unique ID** issue. I had two `<ItemTemplate>` with buttons that had the same ids. (In different grid views. My second one was in a User Control)

Changing the `<asp:Button ID="" />` to a Unique ID solved the post back issue for me.

Just thought I'd post for any one else who tried the other options with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] and if it ends with the ID of the control, rebind the GridView and use Page.FindControl with the event target to find the control that fired the event

Answer (score 1):

My problem was `requiredfieldvalidator`

Solution to that was: I disable it at post back and then re-enable it after the row command.

Answer (score 0):

Did them all and got nowhere then discovered this:  onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand"  on the GridView1 definition line in html.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my version of this problem by removing all event handlers from the GridView, then rebuilding the code, then adding them back in one at a time.

Comment: dont think this would change anything.