# GridView rowcommand on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My C# Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (CheckBox1.Checked == false && CheckBox2.Checked == false && CheckBox3.Checked == false && CheckBox4.Checked == false && CheckBox5.Checked == false && RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                GridView2.DataSource = SqlDataSource5;
                GridView2.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem == null)
                {
                    GridView2.DataSource = SqlDataSource4;
                    GridView2.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    GridView2.DataSource = SqlDataSource6;
                    GridView2.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "select")
        {
            Response.Redirect("xyz.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when i click on Button1 for firing GridView_RowCommand it does not working beacause of PostBack.
When i remove code from PageLoad if(IsPostBack) its working fine.
So how i solve this problem.
I am usig ASP.Net C# SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Almost always when i see `if(IsPostBack)` that should actually be an event-handler. Handle the appropriate events. That'll make the code much more readable and maintainable and probably solves this issue as well.

Comment: @TimSchmelter how i solve this issue?

Comment: @TimSchmelter why don't you post the link to [your answer to similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494730/gridview-rowcommand-event-not-firing) that probably answers this question? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Michael Moore pointed out this is a related question: [GridView RowCommand event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494730/gridview-rowcommand-event-not-firing)

Almost always when i see `if(IsPostBack)` that should actually be an event-handler. Handle the appropriate events. That'll make the code much more readable and maintainable and probably solves this issue as well.

So don't `DataBind` in `Page_Load` on postback if you want that events are triggered. Instead handle events to `DataBind` the `GridView`. Then the `RowCommand` would be triggered first.

In this case it's difficult to suggest what type of events you should handle since the conditions seem to be complex. Maybe you should add another button instead and apply the logic in the click-event handler. Another approach is to handle all events of all involved controls.

So let all checkboxes use the same event handler `CheckBox_CheckedChanged` and call `DataBind` from all other related controls events like from the `RadioButtonList`s `SelectedIndexChanged`-event:

```
protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}

private void DataBind()
{
    if (CheckBox1.Checked == false && CheckBox2.Checked == false && CheckBox3.Checked == false && CheckBox4.Checked == false && CheckBox5.Checked == false && RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        GridView2.DataSource = SqlDataSource5;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            GridView2.DataSource = SqlDataSource4;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            GridView2.DataSource = SqlDataSource6;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```